# Error in populating data to listView

Tags: android

I am trying to access data from SQLite and try to populate that on a ListView. I got error

The following is java code:

```
package com.example.cmas;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static com.example.cmas.MySQLiteOpenHelper.*;



public class SurveyResult extends Activity{

    //ListView lstSurvey;
    SQLiteDatabase profile;
    Cursor cur;
    ArrayList<Candidate> candidates;

    @Override   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.surveylist_main);
                initilizer();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    void initilizer(){


        profile = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this,DATABASE_NAME,null,1).getReadableDatabase();

        cur = profile.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COL_NAME,COL_NAME,COL_FLOOR,COL_AREA,COL_LAT,COL_LONG,COL_PHOTO}, null, null, null, null,null);

        candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();

        if(cur!=null){

            if(!cur.isAfterLast())
                cur.moveToFirst();
            do{

                candidates.add(new Candidate(cur.getString(0),cur.getInt(1),cur.getFloat(2),cur.getFloat(3),cur.getFloat(4),cur.getString(5)));
                cur.moveToNext();
            }while(!cur.isAfterLast());
            cur.close();
        }

        Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        ListView lstCandidates = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstCandidates);
        lstCandidates.setAdapter(new CustomView(this));

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SurveyResult.this.finish();

            }
        });

    }

    public class CustomView extends BaseAdapter{

        Context localContext;

        public CustomView(Context loaContext){
            super();
            this.localContext = localContext;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "herview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            View myView;
            if(convertView==null){
                myView = new View(localContext);
                LayoutInflater myInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.surveylist_main, parent, false);
            }
            else{
                myView=convertView;

            }

            //Need to populate values

            TextView txtName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            TextView noFloors = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtFloors);
            TextView plotArea = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtArea);
            TextView lat = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtLat);
            TextView lng = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtLong);
            TextView photo = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtPhoto);


            txtName.setText("Building Name:"+candidates.get(position).getName());
            noFloors.setText("No of Floors:"+candidates.get(position).getNoofFloors());
            plotArea.setText("Area:"+candidates.get(position).getArea());
            lat.setText("Latitude:"+candidates.get(position).getLat());
            lng.setText("Longitude:"+candidates.get(position).getLng());
            photo.setText("Photo:"+candidates.get(position).getPhoto());


            return myView;
        }

    }

}
```

While running the app I got the following errors:

```
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cmas/com.example.cmas.SurveyResult}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at com.example.cmas.SurveyResult.initilizer(SurveyResult.java:62)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at com.example.cmas.SurveyResult.onCreate(SurveyResult.java:34)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-10 04:27:17.825: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     ... 11 more
03-10 04:28:20.875: I/Process(1736): Sending signal. PID: 1736 SIG: 9
```

While Viewing the page I got error.

Comment: I doubt `profile` is **NULL**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should open the database before using it in query. Try using

```
profile.open();
```

before running

```
cur = profile.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]    {COL_NAME,COL_NAME,COL_FLOOR,COL_AREA,COL_LAT,COL_LONG,COL_PHOTO}, null, null, null, null,null);
```

Comment: Your error is `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.cmas.SurveyResult.initilizer(SurveyResult.java:62)`. what is on line 62? maybe you can add a break point on that line and debug your app and see if something is null there.